# Can I refer to the interval $[0,1]$ as an uncountable union of singletones?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Is it mathematically correct to claim that?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. @Michael No, choice is irrelevant here.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo You're right, no choice is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write, for any set $S$,
$$
S = \bigcup_{x\in S} \{x\}
$$
even though it's not necessarily really... useful.

Comment: Oh, interesting you're mentioning that... The other day someone asked a question if the condition for compact sets that any *open* cover has a finite subcover can be relaxed so that the cover is not necessarily open. The most natural counterexample is actually contained in your answer.